# Erasing list of phrases from list of texts in python

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to erase specific words found in a list. Lets say that I have the following example:

```
a= ['you are here','you are there','where are you','what is that']
b = ['you','what is']
```

The desired output should be the following:

```
['are here', 'are there', 'where are', 'that']
```

I created the following code for that task:

```
import re

def _find_word_and_remove(w,strings):
    """
    w:(string)
    strings:(string)
    """
    temp= re.sub(r'\b({0})\b'.format(w),'',strings).strip()# removes word from string
    return re.sub("\s{1,}", " ", temp)# removes double spaces

def find_words_and_remove(words,strings):
    """
    words:(list)
    strings:(list)
    """
    if len(words)==1:
        return [_find_word_and_remove(words[0],word_a) for word_a in strings]
    else:
        temp =[_find_word_and_remove(words[0],word_a) for word_a in strings]
        return find_words_and_remove(words[1:],temp)

find_words_and_remove(b,a)
>>> ['are here', 'are there', 'where are', 'that']
```

It seems that I am over-complicating the 'things' by using recursion for this task. Is there a more simple and readable way to do this task?

Comment: Does your code work and everything?

Comment: yes,it works. I edited my question with full example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use list comprehension:

```
def find_words_and_remove(words, strings):
    return [" ".join(word for word in string.split() if word not in words) for string in strings]
```

That will work only when there are single words in `b`, but because of your edit and comment, I now know that you really do need `_find_word_and_remove()`.  Your recursion way isn't really too bad, but if you don't want recursion, do this:

```
def find_words_and_remove(words, strings):
    strings_copy = strings[:]
    for i, word in enumerate(words):
        for string in strings:
            strings_copy[i] = _find_word_and_remove(word, string)
    return strings_copy
```

Comment: Although I say for 'phrases' in the title, I wasn't clear in the example.I am sorry. The `words` could be also phrases. I have edited my example to be more clear.

Comment: @MpizosDimitris: I have edited my answer with a different solution.

Comment: as far as I tested it yes. Did you found an example that is not working? both `w` and `strings` are string types.

Comment: I thought that `strings` was a list.  I'll have it edited in a minute.

Comment: I'm not sure if you noticed, but I did edit that solution.

Comment: I have noticed but your code outputs different results from the desired output. It gives a string for each comparison with the `b` values. Have you checked it?

Comment: I just completely changed that solution.  See my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

the simple way is to use regex:

```
import re

a= ['you are here','you are there','where are you','what is that']
b = ['you','what is']
```

here you go:

```
def find_words_and_remove(b,a):
    return [ re.sub("|".join(b), "", x).strip() if len(re.sub("|".join(b), "", x).strip().split(" ")) < len(x.split(' ')) else x for x in a  ]

find_words_and_remove(b,a)
>> ['are here', 'are there', 'where are', 'that']
```

Comment: what about `b = ['yo']` ?? Its about erasing words or phrases. Not strings.

Comment: @MpizosDimitris you are right, dind't think of that, now it should work.